# Past Clutch worries over smell/dust

Tags: brakes, clutch, safety

A while back I was driving my '92 Mitsubishi around for quite some long journeys over a few weeks. The car was given to me, but something didn't seem quite right. After a while, I noticed that there was the smell of burning while changing gear (sometimes) but not all the time. It wasn't quite like the overpowering smell of burnt clutch, but more subtle. Sadly didn't really twig what was happening at the time and being away from home, around several thousand miles got done on the car in that state.

A friend pointed out that it was probably the clutch that was slipping and that by the age of the car it might be asbestos. Obviously, this is a concern because of the number of miles that were done in that state (few thousand).

All the research I have read seems to put the risk on those changing the brakes and clutches of cars that contain asbestos, but I have no idea if I should be "that" concerned. I am concerned I guess because I think if I could smell something then I must be breathing in this dust coming off the clutch every time the gear is changed. I have spent some time on the research papers looking at what the clutches might be and since I have no idea about the age of the clutch, but it could be as old as the car, then it is was before asbestos was banned and therefore I'm concerned that is could damage my health. There seems to be no research on occupants and sure, I have burnt clutches infrequently on other cars over the years (which were more intense) but less much less often.

Later on, I learnt that the previous owner may have adjusted the clutch to make it slip - possibly for launching. I'm not familiar with why they would do this. But of course, the health implications are weighing on my mind for fear of developing a disease like mesothelioma.

As a follow-up...

If it helps the smell was strange, not like the normal overpowering stench. I could not describe it, it wasn't totally unpleasant, a bit like an overheated smell but not I would really describe it as acrid. I've burnt the clutch on much newer cars and they can smell different and be more intense. I'm really trying to understand what I've been breathing in. Has this been a trail of dust from the bell housing somehow into the cabin? What is the smell?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! How many miles are on the car?

Comment: If you breathed the dust from thousands of clutches then you should be worried, but 1 or 2 not likely.

Comment: If it helps you feel any better, [Mitsubishi stopped using asbestos laced products in their vehicles in the early '80's](https://www.drive.com.au/news/giving-health-a-break-ndash-asbestos-banned-for-good-20031102-13kc7/).

Comment: Was about 80k miles on the car. No idea if the clutch was original or not.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks for that. I did read though: Traditionally, brake linings and pads containing asbestos were cheaper than those without, which means many vehicles that may have had asbestos-free brakes originally may have asbestos in the replacement parts.

Comment: @SolarMike Source of your claim?  I don't know the number, but before making a claim like "thousands", multiple well-researched references would be needed.  This is especially true given that you are talking a substance documented to cause cancer.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks. The clutch was obviously slipping for a while and smelt hot. We had the windows open, so no idea how much was coming in. So it worries me when you see the warnings given to mechanics about doing brake jobs.

Comment: @Japobox yes, 8 brake jobs per day, 5 days a week, 47 weeks a year for 10, 15 or 30 years…

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks. Do you have any idea what concentrations would come off a clutch in use - if slipping. Are we talking about an equivalent of a clutch job every 100 miles for example? I know there are environmental levels set. Happy New Year.

Comment: @Japobox apply a bit of common sense: a clutch lasts about 100k, you can find the plate thickness - remember it has two faces. So, a normal clutch may last 8 or 10 years and you can estimate the dust output per year. However if you brush it out when you have the box out that’s different. But you are not a mechanic…

Comment: @SolarMike, yes I hear you. Just dealing with these unknowns. I guess the fundamental question, is when you can smell the clutch, how much more fibre is coming off compared to when it isn't so noticeable.